# Nginx: request files without extension

Tags: nginx

How can I request html pages on a nginx server without the extension?

Ie: example.com/about should return example.com/about.html. This should be true for all the html pages.

I have something along the lines of:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html;
index  index.html;
```

Which works, but visiting example.com/ causes a 403 Forbidden:

```
2015/01/20 19:26:11 [error] 32618#0: *373061 access forbidden by rule
```

And visiting a non existing page (example.com/bla) causes a redirect loop:

```
2015/01/20 19:26:57 [error] 32620#0: *373065 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/bla.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html"
```

updated with complete nginx config:

```
server {
    listen          [::]:80;
    server_name     example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root   /var/www/example/;
    try_files $uri $uri.html /index.html =404;
    index  index.html;
    expires max;
    autoindex off;

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your try_files line to look like the following:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html /index.html =404;
```

The reason you are seeing a loop is that try_files will force a redirect to the last entry if no valid location is found during the search.

Further reading and reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

Comment: Thanks. However, typing /bla now gives me the index.html. No 404? But that's not too bad.

Comment: Try taking off /index.html then, the =404 should redirect to a Page not Found.

Comment: but that's what I had in the beginning: going to example.com/ doesn't work anymore then. I have to request index.html or index.

Comment: You didn't appear to have =404. If that doesn't work, just manually add your 404 page directly

Comment: Updated the original post with the entire config. It now included =4040 and I don't have any separate 404 pages (using nginx' default).

Comment: Updated reference link: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Answer (score 4):

To avoid getting redirected to `/index.html` instead of your 404 in the case of a wrong url, set `try_file` like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html =404;
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, if you don't have $uri/index.html but simply /index.html then you never hit the 404 page. /bla will allways return index.html